# Difficulty in generating an input text file

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation

I am preparing the Ansys input file in Mathematica, It works completely fine with  text, but the moment when I input some numbers I am getting some error. How to overcome this?

```
Y = 2*^11;
Style["/PREP7  
  /RGB,INDEX,100,100,100, 0  \n
  /RGB,INDEX, 80, 80, 80,13   \n
  /RGB,INDEX, 60, 60, 60,14 \n  
  /RGB,INDEX, 0, 0, 0,15  \n
  /REPLOT  \n
  ET,1,LINK180 \n
  ET,2,BEAM188 \n

  !BEAM MATERIAL \n 
  MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  \n
  MPTEMP,1,0  \n
  " "StringForm[" TMPDATA, EX, 1, , `` \n ",Y]" ",Black,15,FontFamily\
\[Rule] " Lucida Console ",LineSpacing\[Rule]{1,0}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for what you want to achieve the current recommended way would be to use the templates functionality. The closest to your example code would be something like the following:

```
parameters = <|"Y" -> 2*^11|>;
inputstr = StringTemplate["/PREP7  
 /RGB,INDEX,100,100,100, 0  
 /RGB,INDEX, 80, 80, 80,13   
 /RGB,INDEX, 60, 60, 60,14   
 /RGB,INDEX, 0, 0, 0,15  
 /REPLOT  
 ET,1,LINK180 
 ET,2,BEAM188 

 !BEAM MATERIAL  
 MPTEMP,,,,,,,,  
 MPTEMP,1,0  
  TMPDATA,EX,1, ,`Y`
 "][parameters]

 Style[inputstr,Black,15,
    FontFamily->"Lucida Console",LineSpacing->{1,0}]
```

Note that there is also `FileTemplate` which might be an even better fit, as you then can separate the template content into an extra file. Also note that you added two line-breaks, which I guess you didn't intent to and that it is generally a good idea to separate string operations from pure formatting (the `Style` stuff you were using). As written it should be straightforward to add other parameters. If you need more control over exact formatting of the parameters (very likely when generating input-decks for ANSYS), you might need to pass preformatted strings as parameter values, e.g. something like:

```
 parameters=<|"Y"->ToString[FortranForm[2.*^11]]|>
```